# How do I add data in a new column on each row within a CSV?

Tags: ruby, csv

So I have a method that looks like this:

```
  csvs = Dir["#{@dir_name}/#{@state}/*.csv"]

  csvs.each do |csv|
    city = csv.split(/[\/]|.csv-updated|.csv/).last
    CSV.foreach(csv, headers: true) do |row|
      temp = extract_email(row['Website'])
      # add result from temp above to existing row
    end
  end
```

Basically what I want to do is, on each `row` that I process within the CSV, I want to do something with the data in `row['Website']` (as represented as `temp` in the snippet above), and then I want to take the result and add it as new columns to that row.

So basically I want to append to a each row. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

Basically, I can't edit an existing CSV like that, so I just have to read all the rows from the `old_csv` and create a `new_csv`. From that `old_csv`, I then pass the corresponding data from the `old_csv` to the method I want (i.e. `extract_email(row['Website'])` and then I process that info and collect the emails in an array.

From there, all I have to do is iterate over the collection of `temp` and add it to the `row` object:

```
temp.each { |t| row << t }
```

Then I just add `row` to the new CSV, which will include the old row + the newly added columns. So in essence I am expanding each `row`.